# SQL to Linq Datatime

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
 var oList = from oCI in db.clients
             where oCI.ClientRef == 20
             select new
             {
                 id = oCI.id,
                 dateReceived = oCI.dateReceived,
             };
```

when accessing dateReceived  i get a value of

```
/Date(1342479600000)/
```

instead of

```
2012-07-17 00:00:00.000
```

stored in the database

can anyone help?

the class

```
 public partial class client
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public long ClientRef { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateReceived { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: can you provide `oCI` class declaration? what type of `oCI.dateReceived`?

Comment: it is selected as a new object no class needed to be defined

Comment: `oCI` is item from `db.client` it's not a selected anonymous object

Comment: Remove the .Value and return the nullable datetime from EF and have consumers check the nullability/value themselves. We're assuming here that you have dateReceived mapped as a DateTime? and not some numeric type.

Comment: @LeBlues what is the _type_ of `oCI`?  The type that includes the `ClientRef` and `dateReceived` properties?

Comment: @Jim Wooley i tried that it still returns same value which i have never see in my life

Comment: @ D Stanley there is no type, it is a temp class, in the database ClientRef  and I?d are int and dateReceived is datetime

Comment: try `dateReceived = (DateTime)oCI.dateReceived`

Comment: still the same result

Comment: What type is `dateReceived` in your anonymous class?

Comment: it should inherit the type from EF class

Comment: Where do you see the value that you are getting?  Is it being displayed in a text box?  Are you looking at it in the debugger?  That looks like a Unix timestamp.

Comment: i return it as a json and i can see it in the results

Comment: @LeBlues all clear, your problem is JSON serialization for datetime. for solving - send string, or unix timestamp, and in js side create Date object from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var oList = (from oCI in db.clients
             where oCI.ClientRef == 20
             select new
             {
                 id = oCI.id,
                 dateReceived = oCI.dateReceived,
             }).ToList().Select(o => new
                        {
                            id = o.id,
                            status = o.dateReceived.ToString()
});
```

the above return date as a string , and it works!!!

Comment: and if you only do the first part does not work??? (adding the ToString)
var oList = (from oCI in db.clients
             where oCI.ClientRef == 20
             select new
             {
                 id = oCI.id,
                 dateReceived = oCI.dateReceived.ToString(),
             }).ToList()

Answer (score 1):

Try oCI.dateReceived.Value.Date instead.

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks for letting me know. I thought it was... Sorry about that!!

Comment: What if you use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(oCI.dateReceived.Value)? you will lose the time though...

Comment: and I guess that Convert.ToDateTime(oCI.dateReceived.Value) will not work either?

Comment: I guess the field in the db is also Datetime? is the value ok until you save it on the db? (what if you debug oList to see the value before being saved?)

Comment: /Date(1342479600000)/

Comment: I think the problem you have might be related to JSON then, not about the query itself

Comment: How are you serializing it? if you are using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer, that's where the issue could be.. you might need to use  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject instead

Comment: that worked kid of, \"id\":9370 how can i avoid c# putting '\' before "

Comment: You could use the yourString.replace(/\\/g, ''); However, I am sure there are nicer solutions. Anyway, I think that will be only displayed when printing it (are u debugging it?). I think the object should be fine

Comment: That's how C# is embedding special characters in a string. Try and use File.WriteAllText() to write it into a file and open it to see what it's there

Comment: it is part of the object json to client , so the field names are not accessible from object

Answer (score 0):

The following may help:

oCI.dateReceived.ToLongDateString()

System.DateTime Methods (LINQ to SQL)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882657(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime.tolongtimestring(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your problem not in getting Date from db, your problem is how you watch results.

When you serialize date to json string your get next string

```
/Date(1342479600000)/
```

its correct serialized date. for get from this Date object you can use for example regex like this

```
var serializedDate = "/Date(1342479600000)/";
var date = new Date(parseInt(serializedDate.match(/Date\((\d+)\)/)[1],10));
```

**NOTE:** I think better will be watch value in debugger, or send on client string representation of date, or possibly unixtimestamp.